# script that runs when an interface appears (not neecssarily goes up)

Tags: arch-linux, usb, network-interface, udev

I have an usb network interface, that appears when I insert an usb key, or sometimes, the usb key is already inserted when I boot my raspberry pi. The usual solution to this problem is to add an udev script, like so:

```
/udev/rules.d/50-stick.rules

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1405", RUN+="/usr/bin/netctl restart usb0"
```

But this is not working, either at boot-up, nor when I (re)insert the stick. Does there exist another way? I'd like to circumvent the udev method and fire-up a script whenever an interface (such as usb0) appears.

EDIT: Why is this not working:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ENV{INTERFACE}=="usb0", RUN+="/usr/bin/netctl restart usb0"
```

Some info:

```
udevadm info /sys/class/net/usb0
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/net/usb0
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/net/usb0
E: INTERFACE=usb0
E: IFINDEX=5
E: SUBSYSTEM=net
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=508278395
E: ID_NET_NAMING_SCHEME=v240
E: ID_VENDOR=ZTE_Incorporated
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=ZTE\x2cIncorporated
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=19d2
E: ID_MODEL=ZTE_Mobile_Broadband
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=ZTE\x20Mobile\x20Broadband
E: ID_MODEL_ID=1405
E: ID_REVISION=5486
E: ID_SERIAL=ZTE_Incorporated_ZTE_Mobile_Broadband_1234567890ABCDEF
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=1234567890ABCDEF
E: ID_TYPE=generic
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:020600:0a0000:080650:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=cdc_ether
E: ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Communications
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
E: ID_PATH=platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-3f980000_usb-usb-0_1_3_1_0
E: ID_NET_DRIVER=cdc_ether
E: ID_NET_LINK_FILE=/usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
E: SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/net/devices/usb0
E: TAGS=:systemd:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I went with this solution (`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-stick.rules`):

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ENV{INTERFACE}=="usb0", RUN+="/usr/bin/netctl restart usb0", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl restart ntpdate"
```